# How do I load <file name>.csv.gz from snowflake stage into a snowflake table?

Tags: datatables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have successfully loaded 1000 files into a Snowflake stage=MT_STAGE.
Every file has exact same schema.
Every file has exact same naming convention    (filename).csv.gz
Every file is about 50 megs (+/- a couple megs).
Every file has between 115k-120k records.
Every file has 184 columns.
I have created a Snowflake table=MT_TABLE.
I keep on getting errors trying to do a "COPY INTO" to move files from stage into a single table.
I've tried countless variations of the command, with & without different options. I've spent 3 days reading documentation and trying to watch videos. I have failed. Can anyone help?

```
copy into MT_TABLE from @MT_STAGE;
```

> Copy executed with 0 files processed

```
copy into MT_TABLE from @MT_STAGE (type=csv field_delimiter=”,” skip_header=1);
```

> Syntax error: unexpected '('. (line 1)

```
copy into MT_TABLE from @MT_STAGE type=csv field_delimiter=”,” skip_header=1;
```

> Syntax error: unexpected '”,'. (line 1)

Comment: with no example of the file, or the commands you have used, or the errors you are getting, there is actually nothing that can be done to "help" you with. Other than telling "it works for me" which is almost as equally unhelpful to you.

Comment: As Simeon said , we need some errors which you encountered and  share sample data and file format  .. someone will shed light .

Comment: 1.
copy into MT_TABLE from @MT_STAGE;
produced this result ===>  Copy executed with 0 files processed.

Comment: 2. copy into MT_TABLE from @MT_STAGE (type=csv field_delimiter=”,” skip_header=1); produced ====>Syntax error: unexpected '('. (line 1)

Comment: 3. copy into MT_TABLE from @MT_STAGE type=csv field_delimiter=”,” skip_header=1; produced===> Syntax error: unexpected '”,'. (line 1)

Comment: ok, additional information I just figured out. I know, because I've done it on my own system, that all these files have 184 columns. I think I just figured out however, that snowflake is seeing extra commas in some records in some fields that is causing it to read those records as having more fields. I'm taking this to mean there must be ',' WITHIN fields that Snowflake is interpreting as being a delimiter. I didn't go in and give every field a name, only C001-C184. Should I go name every field?

Comment: Naming the fields doesn't provide you with any benefit.  This issue as you stated is delimiters in your data.  Are the fields that contain the commas in your data enclosed by double-quotes?  If not, you'll have a very tough time getting them loaded correctly.  Recommend enclosing those fields in double-quotes and then adding the correct parameter to your file format.

Comment: So there are no mechanisms for loading my files and data to the correct columns even if all my files start with header that would match headers I've created in a new snowflake table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per Mike's statement if there are comma's in your data

| col_a | col_b | col c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no comma | one, comma | two,, commas |

```
col_a, col_b, col_b
no comma, one, comma, two,, commas
```

how can anything tell which is the correct way to know what is in what

| col_a | col_b | col c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no comma | one, comma | two,, commas |
| no comma, one | , comma | two,, commas |
| no comma | one, comma, two | , commas |
| no comma, one | , comma, two | , commas |
| no comma | one, comma, two, | commas |
| no comma, one | , comma, two, | commas |

which is the correct line.

So you ether change the field delimeter from `,` to pipe `|` or you quote the data

```
no comma| one, comma| two,, commas
```

double quotes

```
"no comma","one, comma"," two,, commas"
```

single quotes

```
'no comma','one, comma',' two,, commas'
```

The cool thing is, if you change your column delimiter it has to not be in the in the data OR the data has to be quoted.

And if you change to quoting it has to not be in the filed OR it has to be escaped.

OR you can encode as some safe data type like base64 and it takes more space, but now it's transportation transport safe:

```
bm8gY29tbWE,IG9uZSwgY29tbWE,IHR3bywsIGNvbW1hcw
```

Comment: Not necessarily the news I was hoping for, but I get it. thx